# How to change value of parent component's state via the child component?

Tags: reactjs

This is what I am working on:

https://codepen.io/nisofwareengineer/pen/dybeObW?editors=0110

What I want to happen:

Parent = Board ,
Child = Square

After clicking on any one of the nine boxes, the player var of the parent component's state should change from 1 to 2. This means that a X is displayed when one of the boxes is clicked when player var is 1 and O is displayed when one of the boxes is clicked when player var is 2.

This needs to be done via the child

After following this https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/409/how-to-update-parent-state-from-child-component-in-react

I have done the following:

in parent Board:

```
this.changePlayer = this.changePlayer.bind(this)

changePlayer(){
    this.setState({
     player: this.state.player == 1 ? 2 : 1  
    })
  }

renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} player={this.state.player} changePlayer = {this.changePlayer} />;
  }
```

and in child Square:

```
render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({
            value:
              this.state.value == "" && this.props.player == 1
                ? "X"
                : (this.state.value == "" && this.props.player == 2 ? "O" : ""),
          });
          this.props.changePlayer

        } }
      >
```

I was hoping the passed down method changePlayer would allow the parent state var player to change when any of the child component's buttons are clicked

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to call just this.props.changePlayer in your event because this.props.changePlayer is a function. Because you need to do also other stuff in onClick event you can use onMouseUp as an alternative to change your player. You can solve it like this:

```
<button
    className="square"
    onClick={() => {
      this.setState({
        value:
          this.state.value == "" && this.props.player == 1
            ? "X"
            : (this.state.value == "" && this.props.player == 2 ? "O" : ""),
        player: this.props.player == 1 ? 2 : 1
      });                 
    } }
    onMouseUp={this.props.changePlayer}
  >
    {this.state.value}
  </button>
```

The most right way would be to use redux because in react it is not supposed to pass data from child to parent.

Answer (score 1):

in parent:

```
changePlayer(value) {
    this.setState({
      player: value === 1 ? 2 : 1
    })
  }
```

in child:

```
      render() {
    return <button
      className="square"
      onClick={() => {
    let val = this.state.value === "" && this.props.player === 1 ? "X" : (this.state.value === "" && this.props.player === 2 ? "O" : "")
    this.props.changePlayer(val)
      }}>button</button>
  }
```

Comment: Hmm. From what I can gather, the child component will pass val to changePlayer which will then change the parent's state. But, val itself will only evaluate to either 'X' or 'O'. When either of these are passed into changePlayer, then value  will always evaluate to 1 because we will get either 'X' ===1 or 'O' === 1 which will always be false therefore value will be assigned 1 and hence player will be assigned 1. Am I missing something here?